# Why am i unable to access other files from the public directory in this Zend Framework setup?

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

So the .htaccess is located right outside of the public directory. In it is the following:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

In my public folder is the index.php file, which Zend routes to and also the css folder with my css files.

However, when I type [sitename].com/css/test.css, it says "invalid controller specified (css) and goes through the routing instead of trying to access that css folder and file. I am a little confused as to how this works and if someone could help me understand this?

Thanks!

UPDATE

So now I moved the htaccess file to the public directory and changed the last rewrite rule to read just index.php instead of /public/index.php. However, all requests made to [sitename].com are now navigated to [sitename].com/public. I am still unable to access the css folder. Any help?

UPDATE AND ANSWER

Ok, I think I've resolved the issue. I was using PHPFog's hosted setup. I essentially needed TWO .htaccess files. One for the root directory and one in the public directory. In the root directory I used this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

And for the public directory,

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: .htaccess should be in the public directory, not "right outside of"

Comment: Ok moved the htaccess file to public directory. Still having issues as my updated question explains though.

Comment: If you can change your DOCUMENT_ROOT to /full/path/to/public then you should be fine. If not, then add just below `RewriteEngine on`: `RewriteBase /public`

Comment: Wouldn't the CSS folder be `[sitename].com/public/css`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` in there for if the file exists...

But the folder above `public` should even be accessible over HTTP. Only the `public` folder should be and you .htaccess should live in `public`, eg. `public` should be the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of the site.

Comment: `-s` should handle that, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: "'-s' (is regular file, with size)"

Comment: how do i make public the document root?

Comment: @shaan: That depends on your hosting setup.